# TCP data I send is divided into different particles

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket, tcpserver

I try to send data with TCP.

My code as follow:

```
ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 

OutputStream clientOs = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

int[] x = new int[4];
x[0] = 0x01;
x[1] = 0x02;
x[2] = 0x03;
x[3] = 0x04;

for (int a : x) {
    clientOs.write(a);
}
```

I checked sending data from wireshark and I saw it as follow:

```
"109","22.797801000","---$hostIP---","---$sourceIP---","TCP","67","krb524 > 6854 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=18 Win=29056 Len=1 TSval=23099797 TSecr=767724"
"111","23.020747000","---$hostIP---","---$sourceIP---","TCP","68","krb524 > 6854 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2 Ack=19 Win=29056 Len=2 TSval=23099852 TSecr=767778"
```

- The first is             01 (length 1)
- The second package is    020304
  (length 3)

Why I see 2 diffent package. Why doesn't it look like this: 01020304 (length4)

How can I send data as only one package?

Comment: The problem description and example code don't seem to match. The example code doesn't look like it would run as written since trying to set a value to x[3] should blow up when the array is initialized as int[2].  Also, you say that you are getting 03, 04, 05 back, however you never set a 05 value.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is - in contrast to UDP - a *stream* based protocol. This means, you cannot make any assumptions at all, especially not, how the data is split up on individual network packages.

This means in turn, that on the other side, you cannot guess how many data you will get with a single read-call to the tcp socket. If your data is structured, you have to employ an (inband) protocol to reflect this structure (i.e. length bytes, fixed data structures etc.)

Having said that, chances are good, that your data will be sent in a single packet in your case, if you add it together in one byte array and send it with a single call to `write()`. I do not see a reason, why an OS would split it up in this case.

Comment: I think split happens like that because OS sends packet immediately, but of course cannot physically send two packets in parallel. So, first `write()` triggers a send of available data. But it takes time to actually wrap the data (1 byte) in a TCP message, IP packet, Ethernet frame, and send that frame. While that occurs, the next 3 `write()` calls add data to buffer, so when first packet sending is complete, OS immediately grabs available data for sending, now creating a 3 byte packet. I'm just guessing, but seems logical it might be like this.

Comment: "*OS sends packet immediately*" - actually, it doesn't.  TCP sockets have "Send Coalescing" (aka the Nagle algorithm) enabled by default, which prevents exactly that.  When enabled, outgoing data is buffered into more efficient packets over the wire.  The first `write()` will not trigger an immediate send, it will be buffered and the kernel will wait some time before sending it, allowing more bytes to get a chance to be buffered into the same packet.

Comment: You have to explicitly request Nagle be disabled via the [`Socket.setTcpNoDelay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay(boolean)) method if you want data to be sent immediately.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When using the Nagle algorithm, the OS sends a packet immediately, when all other packets are acked, which is trivially fulfilled for the first data to send. So the first byte is sent immediately, even with nagle.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the chance of getting a 1 byte packet you could massage the array of ints into an array of bytes and send the whole byte array with this.

write(byte[] b, int off, int len)

Comment: Which is easier to manage if you wrap the socket `OutputStream` with a `BufferedOutputStream`